# objects showing in Eevee but not cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

So I've been modeling this camera with Eevee along the way and didn't have any problem when switching to rendering mode, however, once I switched the render engine to cycles a lot of the parts are not showing in the viewport.

It is rather weird because the wireframe of the object is still showing when the wireframe is turned on but the object itself is not showing in the viewport or in the render. I checked everything in the outliner and nothing is wrong, I also tried to copy the object that's not showing up to a different blend file think it could be just this file is corrupted but it's still the same.

[image: what it looks like in eevee]

[image: what it looks like in cycles]

Comment: can you share the blend file? (you can remove all other objects than the one that has the problem). In general cycle and eevee have different managements of the shader nodes settings (but you probably already know it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the object properties and visibility (while Cycles is enabled as your renderer) and make sure the "Camera" checkbox is ticked. You can check all the other ones too, I guess.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It must have been turned off when I used the boo tool.